# Confusion on DCGAN generator project & reshape

Tags: machine-learning, gan

I've been recently studying DCGAN.
I tried following implementation from the [pytorch.org DCGAN tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html#generator) and found that it (seemingly) lacks project & reshape layer, which is present in the diagram:

[image]

It really confused me, so I searched for other implementation and found the [tensorflow.org DCGAN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan#the_generator), which further confused me. [The original paper from ArXiv](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan#the_generator) clearly states:

> Notably, no
> fully connected or pooling layers are used.

**But the tensorflow official tutorial is using fully connected(Dense) layer for reshaping!**

I also found the [reference DCGAN implementation](https://github.com/soumith/dcgan.torch/blob/master/main.lua#L90) but no help since I can't understand lua scripts.

So the question is: **what is the proper implementation of generator network from DCGAN paper? Should I omit project and reshape or use dense layer?**

Answer (score 1):

The [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06434.pdf) states:

> The first layer of the GAN, which takes a uniform noise distribution Z
> as input, could be called fully connected as it is just a matrix
> multiplication, but the result is reshaped into a 4-dimensional tensor
> and used as the start of the convolution stack

This matches with [their implementation](https://github.com/Newmu/dcgan_code/blob/ec3721ac941bf12e9f86edb6fa48f1256f40924a/imagenet/load_pretrained.py#L45), where they apply a dot product of the input with some weights, before normalization, activation and reshaping to an image tensor.

So the first layer seems to be a dense layer.